# AWS Bucket Policy using SourceIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I would like to allow access to the S3 bucket by all users using a corporate IP address. I added a Bucket Policy but I'm still getting access denied. Is this possibly because my sourceIp is behind the corporate router?

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "165.70.20.0/22"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does [What's My IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) say your IP address is?

Comment: @Tim - Thank you. After getting the outward facing IP address I'm able to download just fine. If you want to write something as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should determine your public IP address using a website such as [What's My IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/). Once you identify that and put it into your policy things should start to work with your existing policy.

Answer (score 0):

If your corporate router is using NAT then S3 will only see the remapped IP of your external IP address on the router.  If you only want access for your internal corporate network it may be better to create a VPN to a VPC and then an endpoint that is only accessible to the VPC:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

Comment: S3 buckets typically aren't part of a VPC. You'd have to restrict S3 access to a VPC somehow, and I haven't used S3 enough to know the best way. Probably some kind of bucket policy.

Comment: true S3 typically isn't part of a VPC - but if you wanted to lock it down just to your corporate internal network this would be one way to do that.  Otherwise you'll have to  be cognizant of what your external IP addresse(s) are when they are NATted.  Easy enough to find out if it's just one router and static : https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: The downside of this is that your bandwidth to S3 is then limited by VPN throughput / latency. You also lose the benefit of redundant access to S3 endpoints, etc. So in it's an option indeed but I wouldn't do it this way.